# yii2 Setting read-only property: yii\data\Pagination::limit

Tags: php, pagination, yii2

I am trying to set the limit on my active data provider in Yii2 in the pagination to 5 records. Accordingly to [THIS](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html) documentation, the $limit property is available, but I am getting this error:

```
Setting read-only property: yii\data\Pagination::limit
```

And my code is this:

```
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Order::find()
            ->where(['user_id' => $user_id]),
        'sort' =>[
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'id' => SORT_DESC
            ]
        ],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
            'limit' => 5,
        ],
    ]);
```

And my question is this: Why does this happen? The `pageSize` works if I erase the `limit` everything goes smooth... On `limit` everything fails... How can I solve this?

**L.E:** I found the source method that throws this error, in case it helps:

```
    /**
     * Sets value of an object property.
     *
     * Do not call this method directly as it is a PHP magic method that
     * will be implicitly called when executing `$object->property = $value;`.
     * @param string $name the property name or the event name
     * @param mixed $value the property value
     * @throws UnknownPropertyException if the property is not defined
     * @throws InvalidCallException if the property is read-only
     * @see __get()
     */
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $setter = 'set' . $name;
        if (method_exists($this, $setter)) {
            $this->$setter($value);
        } elseif (method_exists($this, 'get' . $name)) {
            throw new InvalidCallException('Setting read-only property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
        } else {
            throw new UnknownPropertyException('Setting unknown property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
        }
    }
```

according to this, it seams I am trying to: `getLimit()` not `setLimit()`... any ideas why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `pageSize` will determine how many rows are shown for each page.

Comment: @Alex i am trying to show only the last 5 records in my DB. I saw the documentation and I thought that I have the limit property available in pagination, but as it turns out, I don't... Check my answer

Comment: I downvoted this question: 1) It's clear from the code that getLimit is an alias for getPageSize method and used for SQL data retriving (e.g. There is not **pageSize** in MySQL but there is a **limit**).  2) What the reason to **set read-only property**? The author explicitly set that this is read-only and you shouldn't set it manually. 3) "Use sources Luke" - just open the source code and find the answer in the code instead of asking stupid question "Why I can't set read-only property".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the Yii [Guid Concept of Properties](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-properties.html)

A property defined by a getter without a setter is read only. Trying to assign a value to such property will cause an [InvalidCallException](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-invalidcallexception.html). Similarly, a property defined by a setter without a getter is write only, and trying to read such property will also cause an exception. It is not common to have write-only properties.

There are several special rules for, and limitations on, the properties defined via getters and setters:

1. The names of such properties are case-insensitive. For example, `$object->label` and `$object->Label` are the same. This is because method names in PHP are case-insensitive.
2. If the name of such property is the same as a class member variable, the latter will take precedence. For example, if the above Foo class has a member variable label, then the assignment `$object->label = 'abc'` will affect the member variable `'label';` that line would not call the `setLabel()` setter method.
3. These properties do not support visibility. It makes no difference for the visibility of a property if the defining getter or setter method is public, protected or private.
4. The properties can only be defined by non-static getters and/or setters. Static methods will not be treated in the same manner.

So in other terms, there is no way do do this only with PHP. As it is said in the documentation, a thing that I just saw:

`$limit public read-only property`

`integer getLimit( )`

*The limit of the data. This may be used to set the LIMIT value for a SQL statement for fetching the current page of data. Note that if the page size is infinite, a value -1 will be returned.*

In order for this to work as expected, the code needs to become this:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Order::find()
        ->where(['user_id' => $user_id])
        ->limit(5),
    'sort' =>[
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'id' => SORT_DESC
        ]
    ],
    'pagination' => false,
]);
```

Hope this helps others in my shoes!

Answer (score 2):

Pagination doesn't have property $limit,

> @property integer $limit The limit of the data. This may be used to set the LIMIT value for a SQL statement

That value set by propery $pageSize.

If you need to get last 5 news and this must be work with pager you need something like this:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Order::find()
        ->where(['user_id' => $user_id]),
    'sort' =>[
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'id' => SORT_DESC
        ]
    ],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 5,
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Many properties in `Yii` are read-only. There are 2 simple ways to find out whether a property is read only or not.

1. Using `canSetProperty()`
2. if there is a method with `set` prefix, for example `setLimit()`

On the other hand, you must set limit on your query, not pagination.

Comment: Yes but I want to set it via pagination because of 2 reasons: one because I can, so why the hell not, and two because a php script runes faster then a query

Comment: @AresDraguna :)) so I suggest you at least use limit in widget that will load this data provider. Anyway, you can not do this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [`ArrayDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html) will be better suited.

```
$query = new Query;
$provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $query->from('post')->limit(5)->all(),
    'key' => 'id',
    'sort' => [
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'id' => SORT_DESC
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: this works with ActiveDataProvider as well, as my answer shows :) it has nothing to do with that... I just wanted to know if I can use the limit property in pagination and why that property is read only